# Illustrator scripting: place image file if it has same name of illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm -slowly- learning how to code using JavaScript in Illustrator, and I'm trying to write a script that automatically picks an image file from a given fixed folder in my hard drive and places it in a fixed position inside the Illustrator file. All of this should happen **if and only if the image has the very same name of the Illustrator file itself (both without the ".something" extension)**

Here's what I have so far:

```
doc = app.activeDocument;

    //images are in this folder
    var dirImages = new Folder("C:\\FolderWithImages");
    var imagesList = dirImages.getFiles();

    var itemToPlace; 


        for (var i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {

            var imgName = imagesList[i].name;
            var documentName = activeDocument.name;

            //compare image filename to current document name (both without extensions)

            var imgNameNoExt = imgName.slice(0, imgName.indexOf("."));
            var docuNameNoExt = documentName.slice(0, documentName.indexOf("."));

                // check identical names
                if( imgNameNoExt == docuNameNoExt ) {

                    itemToPlace.file = imagesList[i];
                    itemToPlace.top = myDocument.height;
                    itemToPlace.left = 0;
                }
         }
```

When I run it I don't get any error code, but I don't get any result either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It came out I wasn't using the most important function to place an item in the canvas :)
here I copy the corrected version of the script (for sure it can be implemented, but right now is already working as a charm)

```
doc = app.activeDocument;

//images are in this folder -yes, you need double "\\" for some reason I still don't know-
var dirImages = new Folder("C:\\FolderWithImages");
var imagesList = dirImages.getFiles();

var itemToPlace = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {

        var imgName = imagesList[i].name;
        var documentName = doc.name;

        //compare image filename to current document name (both without extensions)

    var imgNameNoExt = imgName.slice(0, imgName.indexOf("."));
    var docuNameNoExt = documentName.slice(0, documentName.indexOf("."));

        // check identical names
        if( imgNameNoExt == docuNameNoExt ) {


            // this I was missing!!!!!!!!!!!! 
            var itemToPlace = doc.placedItems.add();

            itemToPlace.file = imagesList[i];
            itemToPlace.layer = doc.currentLayer;
            itemToPlace.top = doc.height;
            itemToPlace.left = 0;

        }
 }
```

Thanks again Joonas for helping me out on this, without your advice, I wouldn't have had the strength to dig more into this and make it work!

Comment: Yup, that would do it :)

Comment: Using forwardslash `/` instead of backslash  solves the double slash problem. I'm guessing you need to use double slash because the first needs to escape the second.

Answer (score 4):

Your `dirImages` path has one extra backslash. Should probably be: `C:\FolderWithImages`?

I tend to just throw alerts in places to figure out where things are going wrong. You might want to try sticking [`alert( dirImages.error );`](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_Folder.html#error) somewhere after it to see if that says there's an error in your path.

Also:

- `itemToPlace` variable doesn't contain an object.

  - Change it to `var itemToPlace = {};`
- In `itemToPlace.top`, you are referencing `myDocument`, which doesn't exist in this code.

  - It should probably be `itemToPlace.top = doc.height;`
- This one isn't an error, but a missed opportunity. In variable `documentName`, you are using `activeDocument.name`, when you could be using `doc.name`.

Comment: hi Joonas, thanks a lot for your precious help!
I implemented all your corrections, now the script is executed without any error  
I tried placing the alert( dirImages.error ); and it comes out blank, so everything looks ok  
but the script keeps not producing any result

I'm already sure there's no capital letters in both documentName and image files, but I will write a couple of lines to convert everything in lowercase just to be sure